# How to put multiple visual elements into a single link in a urdf?

Tags: ros, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know above a certain complexity it is better to move entirely to collada meshes, but I think it would be nice (and preserve the ability to place and scale visual elements within a xacro/urdf) to be able to have multiple visuals within a link like the following, which would create a composite object out of a cube and a cylinder mesh (or a cube primitive or anything else):

```
 <link name="link1">

 <visual name="vis1">
     <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
     <geometry>
       <mesh filename="package://testbot_description/meshes/cud.dae" />
     </geometry>
 </visual>
 <visual name="vis2">
     <origin xyz="0 1.0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
     <geometry>
       <mesh filename="package://testbot_description/meshes/cylinder.dae" />
     </geometry>
 </visual>  
 </link>
```

Right now I'm creating extra fixed joints and links that are purely for visual purposes, it seems like they pollute the xacro and rviz environments.  Is there another way to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101346/how-to-put-multiple-visual-elements-into-a-single-link-in-a-urdf?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2013-11-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A bit late (\o/), but adding multiple `visual` elements to `link`s is (now) allowed. See [wiki/urdf/XML/link](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/link).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-09-26**:
Cool, I'll try it out.

**Comment by [audrius](https://answers.ros.org/users/36573/audrius/) on 2022-03-03**:
multiple collision elements also work.